# Should I send the "update" to the job application after being finally dismissed from my current job?

Tags: job-search

I was already looking for another job, feeling "bad things" around, and have sent a few applications. Nobody replied so far, likely due Corona around.

Recently I have received an official message I am being laid off. I also received a letter of recommendation that is a good, positive letter of recommendation. There is more than one reason to reduce the work force, that's OK.

Would it be helpful for me to send the "update" that I am now available immediately plus one more positive letter of recommendation to several companies I have just applied? Or is it better "not to touch"?

Comment: Why do you believe it's necessary to update your job application? Are you going to mention that you recently got laid off and would like to include a letter of recommendation that you received? No, I wouldn't do this. I would continue applying to positions and then use the letter of recommendation from now on. I remember I've had things change while job searching before, i.e. I learned a new skill, etc. This was just something I had to include on the upcoming job applications.

Comment: Don't touch those applications you already sent.

Answer (score 1):

No need to update that you are fired. Just update you are ready for immediate joining.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't update that I'm available immediately unless the original date is super far away. After all, employers are more likely to want to hire you if they think you still have a job. And knowing that you're available immediately lets them know that you're no longer employed.

Comment: They weren't fired, they were laid off. Those are totally different things.